# Public folder not being packaged with npm run build, getting Welcome to nginx

Tags: reactjs, typescript, docker, nginx, npm

When running `npm run build`, the `dist` folder is created and all files within `src` are compiled. However, none of the files from the `public` folder are included. Therefore, when I use `nginx` to serve my site, I am greeted with the standard "Welcome to nginx" message. Not sure where the issue lies and have been struggling for hours. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Excerpt from my `package.json`

```
...
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "tsc -p tsconfig.json",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "react-hooks",
      "@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": 0
    }
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/dateformat": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/glidejs__glide": "^3.4.0",
    "@types/google-map-react": "^2.1.2",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.8",
    "@types/react-dates": "^21.8.3",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
    "@types/react-sticky": "^6.0.4",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.24"
  },
...
```

My `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

My `Dockerfile`

```
# build stage
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --force
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:1.16.0-alpine
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Project structure

```
app
|-- node_modules
|-- public
|-- src
|-- package.json
|-- README.md
|-- etc...
```

Comment: Your dockerfile doesn't copy the public dir into your docker image, so... start there?

Comment: "build": "tsc -p tsconfig.json"
I use react-scripts build for that, I think issue is with docker file

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans i've made some changes to the build script and it now copies the public folder files into the dist folder. However, now i'm getting a 502 error from nginx.

Comment: Then you know what to do: [docker exec -it bash](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) and start looking at what's going on.